# When a family of exponential distribution is tight?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We want the family of exponential distributions {Exp(λ): λ from A} to be tight. I am looking for necessary and sufficient conditions for a set A.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? I would be really grateful :)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? If you write down what it means for a family of probability distributions on $\mathbb R$ to be tight, it should not be difficult to see what the condition should be.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the convention that the mean is $1/\lambda$. Then
the condition should be $\Lambda$ being a subset of $(0,\infty)$ bounded away from the origin, i.e., there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\Lambda \cap (0,\delta)=\emptyset$. Indeed, one can prove this using the tail probability formula for $Exp(\lambda)$, namely, $P(X>x)=e^{-\lambda x}, x>0$.